# How can I get an Android TableLayout to fill the parent in landscape mode?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am using a TableLayout in my application. It contains four TableRows each containing four ImageViews. The behavior I want is to scale the layout to fit the shortest dimension.

It works fine in portrait mode but fails miserably in landscape mode.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) it looks like this is because the TableRow layout_height is always set to WRAP_CONTENT. While I can set the dimensions of the individual Views, the TableLayout won't render at all if I set the View layout_height to FILL_PARENT.

I feel like there is something simple I am missing. Is there a way to get the TableLayout with TableRows to scale to fit the height in landscape mode?

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*">
</TableLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class Example extends Activity {

private TableLayout mTable;
private int[] mDrawableIds = {  R.drawable.draw01, R.drawable.draw02, R.drawable.draw03, R.drawable.draw04, R.drawable.draw05, R.drawable.draw06,   R.drawable.draw07, R.drawable.draw08, R.drawable.draw09, R.drawable.draw10, R.drawable.draw11, R.drawable.draw12, R.drawable.draw13, R.drawable.draw14, R.drawable.draw15, R.drawable.draw16 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
               ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
               iv.setImageResource(mDrawableIds[j*4+i]);
               iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
               iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
               tr.addView(iv);
           }
        mTable.addView(tr);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does a GridView not work for your use case? GridView tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: GridView seems to want to scroll rather than resize the ImageViews to the landscape layout. Perhaps if I made the image resources smaller that might work. I was hoping to avoid resizing the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did figure out how to do this. Basically, the part that wasn't working the way I wanted was the TableRows. When I changed to landscape, the first two TableRows weren't resizing at all and the third was consuming the remainder of the space. The fourth row wasn't displaying at all.

I figured out that I needed to set the layout_weight of the TableRows to equal values. But, there is no method to do that at runtime, so I built the following layout file, which I called row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/trow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TableRow>
```

Then I used a LayoutInflater to build the row at runtime with the properties I wanted:

```
    mTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, mTable,false);
        TableRow tr = (TableRow)row.findViewById(R.id.trow);
           for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
               View image = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, tr, false);
               ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)image.findViewById(R.id.image);
               ib.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
               ib.setImageResource(mCardIds[j*4+i]);
               tr.addView(ib);
           }
        mTable.addView(tr);
    }
```

Now the TableRows are resizing properly on rotation. I changed the ImageViews to ImageButtons because I decided to add some onClick behavior and I am building those buttons via a separate xml file, but I don't think those details are relevant to the resizing issue.

Comment: add `android:layout_weight="1"` to each column in table heading row solved my problem, nice

Answer (score 4):

Change your XML layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">
</TableLayout>
```

That should make it take up whole screen's height regardless of orientation. See [density independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted solution here but it did not work. What worked is as below:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams pRowTop = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
pRowTop.weight = 1;
mTable.addView(tr, pRowTop);
```